# How do I do string indexing using negative to positive indexes?

Tags: ruby, string

For a given string:

```
string = "hello world"
```

I want to return a string using indexing:

```
string2 = string[-4..2]
string2 = "orldhel"
```

Why does ruby return:

```
string2 = ""
```

PS - I will be iterating the beginning and end of the index by 1 and the initial string index might not necessarily be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in a single range. But you can split it in two valid ranges.

```
string = "hello world"

string[-4..-1] + string[0..2] # => "orldhel"
```

You could write a function that accepts a single reversed range and does this. I'll leave it to you as an exercise.

### Update (don't use this in your actual code)

```
class String
  alias_method :old_brackets, :[]

  def [](idx)
    if idx.is_a?(Range) && idx.begin < 0 && idx.end > 0
      old_brackets(idx.begin..-1) + old_brackets(0..idx.end)
    else
      old_brackets(idx)
    end
  end
end

string = "hello world"

string[-4..2] # => "orldhel"
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to do an if statement for my initial index to see if it's negative. This seems so fundamental, why is this not possible?

Comment: This does not feel fundamental. We're lucky that we even have negative indexes at all. Most languages don't have them.

Comment: I'll trust your feelings then. Thanks for your swift answer Sergio.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Monkeypatching is bad enough by itself. When it's not backed by a good reason, it should be avoided.